# nodejs service deployment with azure service fabric

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to deploy a nodejs based service to Mircosoft Azure using Azure Service Fabric. Has anyone tried that?
Any specific documentation would be helpful.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-multiple-apps and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/quickstart-guest-app

Answer (score 0):

Putting this as an answer since I don't have enough points to comment.

Is the nodejs based service written with Service Fabric, such as a stateless/stateful service? If it's not, guest executables or containers might be what you need.

guest exes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app

containers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers

Comment: Thanks Christina. The Nodejs based service is not written with service fabric.